# Existe el término "hiso" en español?

Tags: ortografía

Sé que el pasado de *Hacer* es *Hizo*.

Recibí un correo y cuando le doy a reenviar veo que la persona escribió "hiso" y el Word no me lo resalta como un error ortográfico.

Entonces porque Word piensa que esta bien escribir "hiso"?

Comment: @Diego Maybe my question should be exist the word "hiso"?, my thought was Word had the proper dictionary. By any way i believe I know all the words.

Comment: El problema puede ser de [MS Word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2662392/es) o de tu cliente de mail

Comment: That's odd.  Spanish sounds like it's spelled anyway though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El término "hiso" no está en el diccionario de la RAE. Aunque el diccionario no sea exhaustivo (no recoge todas las palabras que existen en el idioma), si es un término en español al no estar recogido en el diccionario y no debería estar tampoco en el diccionario de MS Word.

El problema puede estar relacionado con MS Word o con tu cliente de email.